# Merge two xml with substring as key

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-2.0

I have two XML file.

**First XML**

```
<annunci>
    <annuncio>
        <any_info>222</any_info>
        <reference>333</reference>
                .
                .
                <lot_of_info> </lot_of_info>
                .
                .
        <some_info>1</some_info>
     <images>
    
    </images>
</annuncio>
```

**Second XML**

```
<images>
    <img>       
        <url>http://example.com/xml/img/333/somefile</url>
        <type>0</type>
        <public>1</public>
        <share>1</share>
    </img>

      <img>     
        <url>http://example.com/xml-feed/img/333/somefile</url>
        <type>0</type>
        <public>1</public>
        <share>1</share>
    </img>

</images>
```

Merging two XML using first file <reference> (example: 333) and <url> on second file with substring (folder) with same number (example: https://example.com/xml-feed/img/333/file1 and https://example.com/xml-feed/img/333/file2) to get a final XML like this one:

```
<annunci>
    <annuncio>
            <any_info>222</any_info>
        <reference>333</reference>
                .
                .
                <lot_of_info> </lot_of_info>
                .
                .
        <some_info>1</some_info>
     <images>
<img>       
        <url>http://example.com/xml/img/333/file1</url>
        <type>0</type>
        <public>1</public>
        <share>1</share>
    </img>

      <img>     
        <url>http://example.com/xml-feed/img/333/file2</url>
        <type>0</type>
        <public>1</public>
        <share>1</share>
    </img>
     </images>
</annuncio>
```

I try this but with no luck:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    
    <!-- identity template: copies all nodes and attributes as-is -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!-- template to add the <img> elements from the second XML file -->
    <xsl:template match="/annunci/annuncio/images">
        <xsl:copy>
  
            <!-- add the <img> elements from the second XML file that have a matching <url> -->
            <xsl:for-each select="document('second.xml')/images/img[contains(url, /annunci/annuncio/reference)]">
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Because I need to copy just ... with matching URL inside annuncio/annunci/images

Comment: The problem is I have on output.xml ALL img nodes not just the matching one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could modify your second template to this :

```
<!-- template to add the <img> elements from the second XML file -->
    <xsl:template match="images">
        <xsl:variable name="ref" select="../reference"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <!-- add the <img> elements from the second XML file that have a matching <url> -->
            <xsl:for-each select="document('second.xml')/images/img[contains(url, $ref)]">
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

(Although as pointed out in the other answer, using a key for lookups is the best practice.)

To make sure that you don't match sub-patterns of your reference id in the URL you could do something like this :

```
<xsl:for-each select="document('second.xml')/images/img[contains(url, concat('/',$ref,'/'))]">
```

Comment: Do note that given  `<reference>333</reference>` this will also copy an `img` with `<url>http://example.com/xml/img/3334/file1</url>`. If you know more about what you're looking for, use it.

Comment: But there is the same problem I have on output.xml, the result is ALL img nodes not just the matching one.

Comment: Your example contains only one reference, with two images matching that reference, so hard to know what your complete data looks like.

Comment: Sorry about that, you are right. I got a lot of img some matching some not. I need to merge online matching one on the first file

Comment: I have updated my answer (the select in the 'ref' variable was wrong).

Comment: Just works! Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would use a key `<xsl:key name="ref" match="images/img" use="tokenize(url, '/')[last() - 1]"/>` and then e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="/annunci/annuncio/images">
    <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:copy-of select="key('ref', ../reference, doc('second.xml'))"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Don't understand very well, could you explain more?

Comment: @Ugo, I am not sure what you expect me to explain, the `xsl:key` is a top level declaration you would put as a child of `xsl:stylesheet`. It tells the XSLT processor to index `img` elements within `images` elements by the second to last token of the `url` child element (which I think is that number e.g. 333). And then `key('ref', ../reference, doc('second.xml'))` uses the key and the `key` function in the template for `annuncio/images` to pull in the referenced `img` elements from the second document.

Comment: @Ugo If you don't know exactly where the `/333/` token will appear in the `url`, you can remove the predicate from the key definition. That would be the efficient equivalent of the currently accepted answer.